# Get <td> tags to include a newline with zen-coding in Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

With notepad ++, I have a slight problem with tag spacing. Normally, what I see with youtube tutorials is:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div>
            <div>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>

                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>

                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

However when I use zen coding I get:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div>
            <div>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How do I get the tags to indent and be like the first piece of code? Is it a setting or a plugin that I have to remove / install? Im trying to improve my neatness when I code.

Answer (score 0):

In editor SynWrite, Zen Coding (new name: Emmet) has the option "Emmet profile". It affects these intents behaviour.

[image]